# Visualforce IF statement: texted wrapped around apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex

I have a VF page with the following code:

```
<p>Hi {!Report_Owner.Name}, You achieved your target
{!IF(report.formulaMetric = 100,
"!",
" and surpassed it by {!report.differenceFM}% ")} 
You are not required to do anything else. Thank you.</p>
```

Unfortunately, at the moment (when formulaMetric = 101 or higher) it returns the following:

```
Hi Robert, You achieved you target, and surpassed it by #{!report.differenceFM}% 
You are not required to do anything else. Thank you.
```

As you can see, instead of rendering differneceFM at a number (eg 1%) it renderes it as text. I know this is probably something silly I am missing, but how do I make sure that the variable associated with `{!report.differenceFM}` is rendered as apposed to it being recognized as part of a string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
{!IF(report.formulaMetric = 100,"!"," and surpassed it by" +report.differenceFM +"% ")}
```

Comment: I got the following error when trying this: Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Text, received Number. Any ideas?

Comment: Change to: {!IF(report.formulaMetric = 100,"!"," and surpassed it by" +TEXT(report.differenceFM )+"% ")}